# Django form not saving data to database with custom form

Tags: django

I trying to create a form for a parking lot for the user and the form will input their RFID card, their log history, license plate, name and active or not but I can't get Django form to save it to the database

here is my `models.py`

```
from django.db import models

class data(models.Model):
    RFID = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    Log = models.TextField()
    License_Plate = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    Active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

My `forms.py`

```
from django import forms

from .models import data  # import data from models.py


class data_form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = data
        fields = ['RFID',
                  'Name', 'Log', 'License_Plate', 'Active']

class data_custom_form(forms.Form):
    RFID = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'id': 'user-rfid'}),
    )
    Name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={'id': 'user-name',
               'cols': 40,
               'rows': 1
               }))
    Log = forms.CharField(
       widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'id': 'user-log'})
    License_Plate = forms.DecimalField()
    Active = forms.BooleanField()
```

My `views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
from .models import data
from .forms import data_custom_form


def custom_form_view(request):
    custom_form = data_custom_form()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        custom_form = data_custom_form(request.POST)
        if custom_form.is_valid():
            print(custom_form.cleaned_data)
        else:
            print(custom_form.errors)
    info = {
        'form': custom_form
    }
    return render(request, 'parking.html', info)
```

And my template

```
<DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>parking</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <input type="submit" value="save">
        </form>
    </body>

    </html>
```

When I check on the database it didn't save to the database but when I check the shell it printed out exactly what I type
But if I use `data_form` and edit the `views.py` like this:

```
def custom_form(request):
    custom_form = data_form(request.POST or None)
    if custom_form.is_valid():
        custom_form.save()
        custom_form = data_form()
    info = {
        'form': custom_form
    }
    return render(request, 'parking.html', info)
```

It saved to the database. Any help would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea behind `Form` and `ModelForm` is different. `Form` objects does not have `save()` while `ModelForm` objects have.

> Every ModelForm also has a save() method. This method creates and saves a database object from the data bound to the form.

for `Form` you have to create the respective model object and call the `save()` instead.

```py
def custom_form_view(request):
    custom_form = data_custom_form()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        custom_form = data_custom_form(request.POST)
        if custom_form.is_valid():
            print(custom_form.cleaned_data)
            obj = data(
                RFID = custom_form.cleaned_data['RFID'],
                Name = custom_form.cleaned_data['Name'],
                Log = custom_form.cleaned_data['Log'],
                License_Plate = custom_form.cleaned_data['License_Plate'],
                Active = custom_form.cleaned_data['Active']
            )
            obj.save()
        else:
            print(custom_form.errors)
    info = {
        'form': custom_form
    }
    return render(request, 'parking.html', info)
```

Here `data_form()` inherits from `ModelFrom` and `data_custom_form()` inherits from `Form`. Which means that `data_form()` object has `save()` while `data_custom_form()` does not. So, when `using data_custom_form()` (in your case) OR whenever `Form` is used, respective model object has to be created (here it is `data()`) assign values to the fields and `save()`

Comment: Thanks, mate I understand now, you help me learn new thing